# How to prove that Adjusted R^2 is less than R^2

Tags: econometrics, regression, statistics

The adjusted R^2 formula is :

> $$ \overline{R}^{2}=1-\left( \left( 1-R^{2}\right) \cdot   
> > \dfrac{n-1}{n-k}\right) $$

In case of k > 1 , I continue like that;

> $$ \overline{R}^{2}=1-\left( 
>  \dfrac{n-1}{n-k}-\dfrac{n-1}{n-k}R^{2}\right) $$

then

$$
\left( n-k\right) \cdot \overline{R}^{2}=n-k-\left( n-1\right) +\left( n-1\right) R^{2}
$$

so
$$
\left( n-k\right) \cdot \overline{R}^{2}-\left( n-1\right) R^{2}=1-k
$$

but after that I don't know how to proceed, is there someone who has an idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$
SSRes=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2\\
SSTotal=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2
$$

$$
R^2=1-\dfrac{
SSRes/(n-1)
}{
SSTotal/(n-1)
}
$$

$$
\bar R^2=1-\dfrac{
SSRes/(n-k)
}{
SSTotal/(n-1)
}
$$

When $k>1$, the numerator of the second equation will be larger, meaning that the second equation subtracts a larger number from $1$ than does the first equation.

Thus, $R^2\ge \bar R^2.$ $\square$

A way to think about $R^2$ is that it compares the error variance to the total variance, and adjusted $\bar R^2$ does the same but with an estimate of the error variance that is slightly larger. Since that estimate of the error variance is slightly larger, adjusted $\bar R^2$ must be slightly less favorable (slightly smaller).